# Python - Voronoi 2D with plotly express

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scatter-plot, voronoi, plotly-express

I have a 2D-scatter plot made with `plotly express`, including 2 types of points - described in a dataframe column called *'color'* - using the animation frame over time (in seconds).

I'm looking for a way to add a Voronoi diagram to this plot. So far, most of my research has lead me to similar problems solved with `matplotlib` and `scipy`, but nothing with plotly...

Below is a part of the figure code:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x = 'x', y = 'y', color = 'color', 
                 color_discrete_map = {'Red': 'red', 'Blue': 'blue'}, 
                 width=800, height=600, animation_frame = 'time (seconds)') 

fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]["frame"]["duration"] = 90

fig.show()
```

Does anyone know a way to do it? Or a documentation - except the Plotly one, which I went through several times - that could help ?

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0):

Years late. But as far as I know **plotly** does not have a way to solve this problem. I don't think they have a library to generate Voronoi tesselation, nor plot one, "out of the box."

From what I found, **scipy** does have good resources, but the plotting examples tend to use **matplotlib**.

I had the same problem, I wanted these Voronoi lines to be on a map made with **plotly express**. I had to use the code directly from [SciPy's source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.4/scipy/spatial/_plotutils.py#L153-L269), which computes the lines for the diagram. This finally allowed me to plot Voronoi diagram lines on a plotly mapbox plot.

```
import plotly.express as px
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
vor = Voronoi(centers)

kfig = px.scatter_mapbox(df)
vor = Voronoi(df.centers)

center = vor.points.mean(axis=0)
ptp_bound = vor.points.ptp(axis=0)


# source!: SciPy
finite_segments = []
infinite_segments = []
for pointidx, simplex in zip(vor.ridge_points, vor.ridge_vertices):
    simplex = np.asarray(simplex)
    if np.all(simplex >= 0):
        finite_segments.append(vor.vertices[simplex])
    else:
        i = simplex[simplex >= 0][0]  # finite end Voronoi vertex

        t = vor.points[pointidx[1]] - vor.points[pointidx[0]]  # tangent
        t /= np.linalg.norm(t)
        n = np.array([-t[1], t[0]])  # normal

        midpoint = vor.points[pointidx].mean(axis=0)
        direction = np.sign(np.dot(midpoint - center, n)) * n
        if (vor.furthest_site):
            direction = -direction
        far_point = vor.vertices[i] + direction * ptp_bound.max()

        infinite_segments.append([vor.vertices[i], far_point])

fsidx = None
for i, fs in enumerate(finite_segments):
    fsidx = i
    st = fs[0]
    end = fs[1]
    kfig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+lines",
    lon = [ st[0], end[0] ],
    lat = [ st[1], end[1] ],
    marker = {'size': 5}))
    

ifidx = None    
for i, fs in enumerate(infinite_segments):
    ifidx = i
    st = fs[0]
    end = fs[1]
    kfig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+lines",
    lon = [ st[0], end[0] ],
    lat = [ st[1], end[1] ],
    marker = {'size': 5}))

kfig
```

[image]